# Call Javascript Function From Server Side C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gif

I created a report that shows a list of manifests. The user can search through this list by the manifest number. When the code is running the search, I'm displaying a Gif:
[image]

But this Gif won't disappear once the search is finished. I can see the correct record is being displayed so the search is over, but the Gif stays on the screen.

The function is called when the search button is clicked.

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btnSearch loading" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" OnClientClick="ShowLoadingGif()" ToolTip="Search" />    

<div id="dvLoading">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="tdLoadingSave"><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>            
    </div>

    function ShowLoadingGif() {
                closefiltermenu();
                $("#tdLoadingSave").html($("#tdLoadingSave").html() + "<br/> Please wait, manifest list is loading");
                $('#dvLoading').fadeIn("500");
        }

 function CloseLoadingGif() {
        $('#dvLoading').fadeOut("500");
    }
```

The search is then run from another function:

```
 protected void Search()
    {
        string Field = ddlSearchBy.SelectedValue;
        string SearchString = txtSearchBy.Text;

        string[] SearchFields = null;
        string[] SearchStrings = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString) && Field != "null")
        {
            SearchFields = new string[] { Field };
            SearchStrings = new string[] { SearchString };
        }

        List<lookupManifestAnalysis> main = lookupManifestAnalysis.SearchManifestItems(Company.Current.CompanyID,
                SearchStrings,
                SearchFields);

        gvResults.DataSource = main;
        gvResults.DataBind();

        udpResults.Update();

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Search", "CloseLoadingGif();", true);

    }
```

But how do I stop the Gif displaying once the search is over?

Comment: `$('#dvLoading').fadeOut("500");` when the search is over (ajax response or whatever you use to know when it's over).

Comment: @pistou The search is run in another function  protected void Search(). Not in jquery. So how would I stop the gif showing from there?

Comment: using `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` in that `Search()` function.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed I added ` ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Search", "CloseLoadingGif();", true);` but it still doesn't work

Comment: try with `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`

Comment: @WaqarAhmed no that still didn't work

Comment: Show your complete efforts. Search and CloseLoadingGif functions.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed ok all code is added to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "CloseLoadingGif","CloseLoadingGif();", true);
```

**OR**
If you are dealing with asp.net UpdatePanel and UpdateProgress, use the following code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(myUpdatePanelID,myUpdatePanelID.GetType(),"CloseLoadingGif", "CloseLoadingGif();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing your code in Server side ASP you should not use client side function for showing or hiding elements. Instead try using Ajax Controls from .Net.

You will need to use AJAX Progress control. Here have a look :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx